# Transversing through a nested map

Tags: c++

How do I transverse through a nested map?
I want to access the value in the second nested map

```
int main ()
{

  std::map<int, int> cool;
  cool.insert(make_pair(8,9));

  std::map<char, std::map<int, int> > mmap;
  mmap.insert(std::make_pair('a', cool));
  cout << mmap['a'][8];

  std::map<char, map<int, int> >::iterator itr;
  for(itr = mmap.begin(); itr != mmap.end(); itr++){
    cout << itr->second << endl;
  }

  return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Your `itr` points to a `pair<char, map<int, int> >`,
so its `second` is a `map<int, int>`,
so an iterator into *that* will do the trick:

```
for(map<int, int>::iterator itr2 = itr->second.begin(); itr2 != itr->second.end(); ++itr2){
  cout << itr2->second << endl;
}
```

Comment: Quick question, why can i not dereference like *(itr) like that for Lists and Vectors and Deques?

Comment: @YaGetMeh: You can. But I find the arrow tidier.

Answer (score 1):

With C++17 you can use structured binding to accomplish this:

```
for (auto const& [key, val] : mmap) {
  for (auto const& [k, v] : val) {
    std::cout << key << " " << k << " " << v << '\n';
  }
}
```

Comment: This style is more and more like python :)